# How do I update a summary table with a trigger?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I am working with the sample [DVD_Rental database](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/). I have to create a trigger on my category_performance_details table that will create a summary table every time data is added to the detail table.

These are the queries I am using to setup my tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS category_performance_summary;
CREATE TABLE category_performance_summary (
    genre VARCHAR(25),
    total_sales numeric
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS category_performance_details;
CREATE TABLE if not exists category_performance_details (
    category_id Int,
    category_name VARCHAR(25),
    film_id Int,
    film_title VARCHAR(255),
    film_rental_rate numeric(4,2),
    inventory_id Int,
    payment_id Int,
    payment_amount numeric(4,2),
    rental_id Int,
    rental_date Timestamp
);
```

I want to update the summary table after every insert statement with a trigger so that it provides a summary of the total sales per category. Basically, the summary table should be the same result as:

```
SELECT category_name, SUM(payment_amount) FROM category_performance_details
GROUP BY category_name;
```

This is my procedure and trigger. For some reason, I am getting a syntax error at or near "CREATE TRIGGER". Am I approaching this trigger correctly? What is wrong with my syntax?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_summary_table()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
    AS
$$
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE category_performance_summary;
    INSERT INTO category_performance_summary (genre, total_sales)
    SELECT category_name, SUM(payment_amount)
    FROM category_performance_details
    GROUP BY category_name;
    
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$


CREATE TRIGGER update_summary
    AFTER INSERT
    ON category_performance_summary
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_summary_table();
```

Comment: Missing semicolon before `CREATE TRIGGER`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply increment or decrement the `total_sales` in the trigger function.

In any case you have to use the `NEW` (resp. `OLD`) key word in order to refer to the values that are inserted/updated (resp. deleted) in table `category_performance_summary` :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment_summary_table()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
    AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO category_performance_summary (genre, total_sales)
    VALUES (NEW.category_name, 1)
    ON CONFLICT (genre) DO UPDATE
    SET total_sales= total_sales + 1
    WHERE genre= NEW.category_name ;
    
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ ;

CREATE TRIGGER increment_summary
    AFTER INSERT
    ON category_performance_summary
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE increment_summary_table();


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION decrement_summary_table()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
    AS
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE category_performance_summary 
    SET total_sales= total_sales - 1
    WHERE genre= OLD.category_name ;
    
    RETURN OLD;
END;
$$ ;

CREATE TRIGGER decrement_summary
    AFTER DELETE
    ON category_performance_summary
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE decrement_summary_table();
```